# Parse JsonArray to custom array

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm trying to parse an jsonarray to a custom array using gson. This is what I did until now

```
try {
        String jsonData = response.body().string();
        JSONObject mObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);

        JSONArray movies = mObject.getJSONArray("results");

        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Movie>>(){}.getType();
        List<Movie> movieList = mGson.fromJson(movies.toString(), listType);

     } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG + " Failure 1", e.getMessage());
     } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d(TAG + " Failure 2", e.getMessage());
     }
}
```

The JSONArray has data but when I try to create the movieList, doesn't work right because the objects inside the list are empty.

[image]

I don't know too much about parsing from Json. Does anyone know how to solve it?

This is my movie class:

```
public class Movie implements Serializable{

private String movieOriginalTitle;
private String moviePoster;
private String movieSynopsis;
private String movieRate;
private String movieRelaseDate;


public String getMovieOriginalTitle() {
    return movieOriginalTitle;
}

public void setMovieOriginalTitle(String movieOriginalTitle) {
    this.movieOriginalTitle = movieOriginalTitle;
}

public String getMoviePoster() {
    return moviePoster;
}

public void setMoviePoster(String moviePoster) {
    this.moviePoster = moviePoster;
}

public String getMovieSynopsis() {
    return movieSynopsis;
}

public void setMovieSynopsis(String movieSynopsis) {
    this.movieSynopsis = movieSynopsis;
}

public String getMovieRate() {
    return movieRate;
}

public void setMovieRate(String movieRate) {
    this.movieRate = movieRate;
}

public String getMovieRelaseDate() {
    return movieRelaseDate;
}

public void setMovieRelaseDate(String movieRelaseDate) {
    this.movieRelaseDate = movieRelaseDate;
}
```

And this is a value of the JSONArray

```
{"vote_count":1126,"id":337167,"video":false,"vote_average":6.1,"title":"Fifty Shades Freed","popularity":542.892558,"poster_path":"\/jjPJ4s3DWZZvI4vw8Xfi4Vqa1Q8.jpg","original_language":"en","original_title":"Fifty Shades Freed","genre_ids":[18,10749],"backdrop_path":"\/9ywA15OAiwjSTvg3cBs9B7kOCBF.jpg","adult":false,"overview":"Believing they have left behind shadowy figures from their past, newlyweds Christian and Ana fully embrace an inextricable connection and shared life of luxury. But just as she steps into her role as Mrs. Grey and he relaxes into an unfamiliar stability, new threats could jeopardize their happy ending before it even begins.","release_date":"2018-02-07"}

{"vote_count":6697,"id":269149,"video":false,"vote_average":7.7,"title":"Zootopia","popularity":340.221253,"poster_path":"\/sM33SANp9z6rXW8Itn7NnG1GOEs.jpg","original_language":"en","original_title":"Zootopia","genre_ids":[16,12,10751,35],"backdrop_path":"\/mhdeE1yShHTaDbJVdWyTlzFvNkr.jpg","adult":false,"overview":"Determined to prove herself, Officer Judy Hopps, the first bunny on Zootopia's police force, jumps at the chance to crack her first case - even if it means partnering with scam-artist fox Nick Wilde to solve the mystery.","release_date":"2016-02-11"}
```

Comment: What's the issue exactly? Gson automatically parsed it

Comment: Please add your JSON data and Movie class to the question

Comment: The json data too? Gson requires you add an empty constructor for your class, by the way

Comment: @cricket_007 I updated the info

Comment: Why don't you have every field of the JSON in your Movie class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Movie class. Adding "movie" to your fields is redundant.

And by default, all JSON keys must match exactly to the Java fields for Gson to work.

For example, `movieOriginalTitle` should instead be `original_title`

Overall, I recommend that you read the [Gson documentation](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support)